# Formatting SSN using string member functions

Tags: c++

What are some different ways I can modify a string holding ssn so that

123-45-8999 becomes XXX-XX-8999 ?

Must use string member functions to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? There are many possible ways to do this, and listing them all seems unnecessary.

Comment: I thought about using s.replace but it appears to replace only with string object.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace):

```
std::string s = "123-45-8999";

s.replace(0, 6, "XXX-XX");
```

If the field widths are dynamic, you can combine this idea with the [string tokenization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13112901/596781) we did just earlier to get something more flexible.

Comment: Hey, What if the string size is not known? How can I replace characters in a string of unknown size?

Comment: @TexQas: Yes, see the other question. You can use `find` to find the location of the separators.